# One JavaScript confirm delete function for all foreach loop collection items

Tags: javascript, php

My PHP code contains a foreach loop that creates arrays (called a quotation) from a collection (called quotations). Each quotation contains a delete button with an id that is then fed (as a parameter) into a Confirm Delete JavaScript function.

The challenge is that the first quotation has the specified id so the JavaScript function works correctly. However, for the quotations that come after, there is no specified id so they are deleted immediately when their delete buttons are clicked with no Confirmation prompt.

I tried to vary it using getElementsByClassName but that didn't work.

Here is a snapshot of the foreach loop creating the variables:

```
@foreach($quotations as $quotation) 

<article style="padding-bottom: 30px">

<div class="body w3-container">Service Request: - {{ $quotation->service_requests->service_name }}</div>

<h5>

<p><strong>Days to complete service: </strong>{{ $quotation->days_to_complete }}<br><strong>Fees to be charged for service (KES): {{ $quotation->fees_for_service }}</strong> <br><strong>Additional terms: </strong>{{ $quotation->additional_terms }}</p>

<a href='service_requests/{{ $quotation->service_request_id }}/quotations/{{ $quotation->id }}/edit' class="pure-button button-xsmall" id="smallLinkButton" style="background-color: #478dff; color: #ffffff;">Edit Quotation</a>

{{ Form::model($quotation, ["route" => ["service_requests.quotations.destroy", $quotation->service_requests->id, $quotation->id], "method" => "delete"]) }}

{{ Form::button("Delete Quotation!",["type"=> "submit", "class" => "pure-button button-xsmall", "id" => "revDel", "style"=>"background-color: #ff4747; color: #ffffff"]) }}

{{ Form::close() }}

</h5>

</article>

@endforeach
```

Here is a snapshot of the Confirm Deleted JavaScript function:

```
<script>

document.getElementById("revDel").onclick = function(f) {my2ndFunction(f)};

function my2ndFunction(f) {

if (confirm("Confirm delete!")) {

}

else {

f.preventDefault();
}

}

</script>
```

Here is a snapshot of how the variables look on my view[image]

How can I change the JavaScript function or the foreach loop (or whatever needs to be changed) so that I get the confirm delete prompt for each listed quotation and not just the first one?

Comment: what framework are you using?

Comment: I had a problem similar to yours. After some research I checked that the problem was in javascript not recognizing the array created in php. Solution use Json, or a method in which you do not need to use arrays.

Comment: I'm using Laravel @JosanIracheta

Comment: Could you include a sample of the code you used that solved this problem? @JoseMarques

Comment: If you wait a few hours I can, put my code available for viewing. But right now I'm working on my leisure pc.

Comment: I'm looking forward to seeing it but in the meantime, noyanc's solution below works really well. Thanks for your input all the same. @JoseMarques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given all buttons the same id. id are supposed to be unique. the DOM will only recognise the first one. Either give them all names attributes and use the getElementsByName method to get a list of button object and itterate through the node list and set onclick or do this.

```
{{ Form::button("Delete Quotation!",["type"=> "submit", "class" => "pure-button button-xsmall", "onclick" => "my2ndFunction(event)", "style"=>"background-color: #ff4747; color: #ffffff"]) }}
```

make sure to remove this line

```
document.getElementById("revDel").onclick = function(f) {my2ndFunction(f)};
```

Comment: Excellent solution noyanc. This works very well. Thanks! :)